# how to replace pairwise characters in a string using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dynamic-programming

Suppose I have a string :

```
x="AAAABBABAABCCABBCA"
```

and I have the following information :

```
AAA=1
ABB= ignore/remove from final output
ABA=2
ABC=3
CAB=4
BCA= ignore/remove from final output
```

so when I translate `x` the output `y` should be:
                 `y=1234`

I tried:

```
def fun(x):
    x=x.replace("AAA","1") 
    x=x.replace("ABA","2")
    x=x.replace("ABB","")
    x=x.replace("ABC","3")
    x=x.replace("BCA","")
    x=x.replace("CAB","4")
    print x
```

But it is giving me the wrong answer:  `123CCA`

I also tried:

```
def fun(x):
    z=[]
        for i in range(0,(len(x)+1)):
            if i=="AAA":
                i=i.replace("AAA",1)
        z.append(i)
        elif i=="ABA":
            i=i.replace("ABA",2)
    elif i=="ABB":
            i=i.replace("ABB","")
    elif i=="ABC":
            i=i.replace("ABC",3)
    elif i=="BCA":
            i=i.replace("BCA","")
    elif i=="CAB":
            i=i.replace("CAB","4")
        z.append(i)
    print ",".join(z)
```

But there is something wrong with the syntax.

So the main problem is to check the string from the beginning and replace the characters.
Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: So if my string is "AAAABCBCAAAA" it returns "13" because "BCA" stopped the translation before it saw the final "AAA"?

Comment: For the first example it would be helpful to include the output you are getting and how it differs from what you expect. For the second example, you should probably include the errors you are getting when executing.

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI --No it should simply ignore that term

Comment: I think it should be `1234`?  based on `[('A', 'A', 'A'), ('A', 'B', 'B'), ('A', 'B', 'A'), ('A', 'B', 'C'), ('C', 'A', 'B'), ('B', 'C', 'A')]`?

Comment: Should the script assume valid input and split the string into a list of 3 character codes on which it runs the translation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution that will properly print `1234` when run over your string :

```
x = "AAAABBABAABCCABBCA"
newstr = ''
for i in range(0,len(x),3):
    part = x[i:i + 3]
    if part == 'AAA':
        newstr += '1'
    elif part == 'ABA':
        newstr += '2'
    elif part == 'ABC':
        newstr += '3'
    elif part == 'CAB':
        newstr += '4'
print newstr
```

If a sequence of three characters doesn't do anything, there's not much point in having it check for it; just quietly continue on to the next one.

If you have your heart set on using `str.replace` to replace these strings within your code, you should look at the optional third parameter `count`.  If you limit it to a single replacement each loop, you should achieve your desired result.

Comment: Thank you @Brien.. That was I typo ..yes the output is 1234.. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

As a pythonic way you can use a [grouper function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) to group your string based on a specific length and put your patterns within a dictionary :

```
>>> d ={'ABA': '2', 'ABB': '', 'ABC': '3', 'AAA': '1', 'BCA': '', 'CAB': '4'}
>>> def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
...     "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
...     # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
...     args = [iter(iterable)] * n
...     return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)
... 
>>> from itertools import izip_longest 

>>> ''.join([d.get(''.join(i),'') for i in grouper(x,3)])
'1234'
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `dict` to store your rules, so that you don't have to keep updating your code every time your rule changes. You can simply update the rules dictionary and your function should keep working.

```
rules = {'AAA': '1',
         'ABB': '',
         'ABA': '2',
         'ABC': '3',
         'CAB': '4',
         'BCA': ''}

def fun(str, rules=rules, substr_length=3):
    newstr = []
    for i in range(0, len(str), substr_length):
        substr = str[i:i+substr_length]
        newstr.append(rules[substr])

    return ''.join(newstr)

print fun("AAAABBABAABCCABBCA")
```

Comment: Why do you want to create an intermediary list when it's not needed?

Comment: Fair enough, updated the answer to store it in a list and return a string.